# Strange behavior of PHP recursive iterators

Tags: php, recursiveiterator

I found a very strange behavior of PHP recursive iterators. It does not iterate over children if children array keys are not numeric keys starting from 0. Example follows:

```
class Foo{

  private $id, $children;

  public function __construct($id, array $children = array()) {
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->children = $children;
  }

  public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
  }

  public function hasChildren()
  {
    return count($this->children) > 0;
  }

  public function getChildren()
  {
    return $this->children;
  }

}

class Baz implements RecursiveIterator {

  private $position = 0, $children;

  public function __construct(Foo $foo) {
    $this->children = $foo->getChildren();
  }

  public function valid()
  {
    return isset($this->children[$this->position]);
  }

  public function next()
  {
    $this->position++;
  }

  public function current()
  {

    return $this->children[$this->position];
  }

  public function rewind()
  {
    $this->position = 0;
  }

  public function key()
  {
    return $this->position;
  }

  public function hasChildren()
  {
    return $this->current()->hasChildren();
  }

  public function getChildren()
  {
    return new Baz($this->current());
  }
}
```

The following works as expected:

```
// Children array keys are numeric and starts from 0. It works.
$foo = new Foo(1, array(
   new Foo(2,
   array(new Foo(3)))
));

foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new Baz($foo), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $j) {
  var_dump($j->getId());
}
```

Outputs:

```
int 2
int 3
```

Now same code but children keys starts from 2:

```
// Now array keys starts from 2 and it does not work.
$foo = new Foo(1, array(
  2 => new Foo(2,
    array(3 => new Foo(3)))
));

foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new Baz($foo), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $j) {
  var_dump($j->getId());
}
```

Output is empty.

Is it bug or what? PHP version is 5.3.27/Windows x86

Comment: Your `Baz` class starts with `$position = 0`. What do you expect?

Comment: Oh thank you, my eyes glaze over